# Valid locations for propagated MIT/BSD licenses?

Tags: mit, bsd, license-file

## Background

My own project is a module for Python (without GUI, so [this answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/1832/982) does not fully apply). It’s licensed with a three-clause BSD license which resides in a separate file (say `License`), and only there.

In this project, I want to use code from NumPy’s [`randomkit.h`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/randomkit.h) and [`randomkit.c`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/randomkit.c), which is modified and strongly reduced for my specific needs. This is the only external code in my project and it resides in its own file (say `random.c`).

#### License of the employed code

The Randomkit files contains the following in its license/copyright statement:

- An MIT license¹ as the main license (extended by the following), stating amongst others:

  > The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
- Quoted as the license for parts is a the three-clause BSD license¹, stating amongst others:

  > Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
- Also included are some further acknowledgements which are part of the copyright notice mentioned by the MIT license.

---

<sup>¹ I didn’t compare those word by word.</sup>

## Actual question

Which are valid or best-practice ways to mention those licenses? I can think of the following (in order of increasing obnoxiousness):

1. Add Randomkit’s license to `random.c` mentioning my own modifications and add a sentence to `License` along the lines of:

   > The file `random.c` is based on NumPy’s Randomkit; see that file for its copyright and license.
2. Add Randomkit’s license to `License`; add a sentence to `random.c` along the lines of:

   > This file is based on NumPy’s Randomkit. See the file “License” for its copyright and license.
3. Add Randomkit’s license to both, `random.c` and `License`.

Comment: I don't consider any of them obnoxius.  Clarity is good, so I would do (3).

Answer (score 3):

Add and/or keep existing notices is the best way to go at the file level and a top level summary helps. More is best e.g. 3. such that you can cover the case of source and binary redistribution more easily.

You could also consider using SPDX-License-Identifier in the files and keep only a top-level notice. This is something that I am helping with in the Linux kernel for instance.

Now, for a Python project, the `setup.py` license arg and the trove classifiers are a way to start. You could also include all this narrative in your top level `LICENSE` file: if you build a wheel, and if your licensing file is named LICENSE, put this in your `setup.cfg` to include the license in the built wheel:

```
[metadata]
license_file = LICENSE
```

You would get belt and suspenders this way. And extra credits for being nice.